# React native duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, react-native

I have an old React native project and started upgrading but getting below errors for ios build

```
    /Users/dharmesh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MoneyCell-dpgseeknkfhvlwcjheohlbwrtlnj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper-Folly/libFlipper-Folly.a(Conv.o)
    /Users/dharmesh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MoneyCell-dpgseeknkfhvlwcjheohlbwrtlnj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCT-Folly/libRCT-Folly.a(Conv.o)
duplicate symbol 'folly::makeConversionError(folly::ConversionCode, folly::Range<char const*>)' in:
    /Users/dharmesh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MoneyCell-dpgseeknkfhvlwcjheohlbwrtlnj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper-Folly/libFlipper-Folly.a(Conv.o)
    /Users/dharmesh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MoneyCell-dpgseeknkfhvlwcjheohlbwrtlnj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCT-Folly/libRCT-Folly.a(Conv.o)
ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 3):

Change in your Podfile

```
use_flipper!()
```

to

```
use_flipper!({ "Flipper-DoubleConversion" => "1.1.7" })
```

source https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/32016